# Rotate a feature at runtime and update a layer

Tags: android, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

i have some objects on the map (lets say cars). These cars produce their own location and accordingly bearing updates. Whenever we get data-updates for objects we create new

```
Feature feature = Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(car.getLongitude(), car.getLatitude())
);
```

build a `FeatureCollection` from all car-features and update our source (in our case a `GeoJsonSource`).

My problem is, that i want to rotate the symbols by `car.getBearing()` to indicate the direction the car is driving to. I checked the explanation for runtime styling (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/) and tried to achieve the same behavior in android, but in contrast to gl-js there:

- is an icon-rotate property for the symbol layer but it expects a rotation value when setting up the layer (default here is simply 0)
- there is no build-in property `"bearing"` for the feature object which could be set (Not in `Feature`, `FeatureCollection` or `Point`)

Is the idea in android to create a layer every time the data-source updates ? I already found a workaround by using `Annotations` but it feels like a) it is possible to get the desired function by using a `SymbolLayer` and b) it would be the much better approach when it comes to large datasets.

The mapbox-gl-native github repos seems to have a `rotate` property for `symbol_instance` but i can't figure out how to use this.

Thanks for any hint on that topic.

Br, Ben